# Update /etc/group in AIX with sed

Tags: sed, aix

I need to add Centrify/AD accounts to local root groups, which is why I need to manually edit /etc/group as the AD accounts are not recognized via adding the "proper" way, across all of our servers comprised of Linux and AIX.  I have the Linux portion working:

```
LGRP=`grep wheel /etc/group`

ACCT="cycoprts"

sed -i "s/${LGRP}/&,${ACCT}/" /etc/group

sed -i "s/${LGRP}/&${ACCT}/" /etc/group
```

The first command adds in a comma if there is an existing entry in /etc/group, the second command skips the comma if there are no other users added to the group.

When I test the same command in AIX (without the -i since it's AIX), I get the following (I'm not actually testing with /etc/group, using /etc/test on my end as a "dummy" test file):

```
AGRP=`grep w3b3root /etc/group`

ACCT1="cycorpad"

root@xxxxxxxxxxx:/etc$ sed "s/${AGRP}/&${ACCT1}/" /etc/group
```

```
sed: 0602-404 Function /w3b3root:!:16:/&cycorpad/ cannot be parsed**
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have `/s` at the start, which I presume should be `s/` (unless you've made a typo transferring the command to your post).

Comment: There is a typo in the `sed` command. Did you mean `sed "s/${AGRP}/&${ACCT1}/" /etc/group`? Maybe use `set -x` to see the commands that actually get executed. Just in case: Please copy&paste the exact command you used on your system. You might introduce or remove errors when you re-type it here.

Comment: Yep, I typo'ed it when typing in the post.  I'm not posting from my work laptop, so I manually typed in everything

Comment: **root@xxxxxxx:/etc$ set -x**
root@xxxxxxx:/etc$ sed "s/${AGRP}\/&${ACCT1}/" /etc/test
**+ sed s/w3b3root:!:16:\/&cycorpad/ /etc/test**
sed: 0602-404 Function s/w3b3root:!:16:\/&cycorpad/ cannot be parsed.
**root@xxxxxxx:/etc$**

Comment: Worth noting: groups in Active Directory can be nested (i.e. a group can be a member of another group), but groups in unix cannot be nested.   Many years ago I had to write a perl script to recursively expand AD nested groups to create a unix groups file (because the people running the university's AD server wouldn't install the AD unix extensions so I had to DIY for my faculty's linux servers).   I used libnss-extrausers rather than modifying /etc/groups directly.

Comment: BTW, your script with command substitutions and sed -i seems prone to disastrous errors - there's no error checking so any problem at any step of the script can break your /etc/groups file (using shell variables in sed scripts is notoriously fragile).   Personally, I'd be inclined to use awk or perl because they can both easily parse a file with `:` delimited fields.  perl has a built-in join() function for the usernames field of /etc/groups (so you don't need extra code to handle single member and multiple member groups), but it's easy enough to write your own join function in awk.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Join-Function.html for an example GNU awk implementation or use the slightly simpler `function join(sep,array,       i) { result=array[1]; for (i=2;i<=length(array);i++) result = result sep array[i]; return result; };`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, removing the unsupported "-i" means, that results are NOT written back to the file - instead it'll likely just print the result of modification to stdout.

To fix this:

Either have a look, if the AIX machines have "gsed" installed, and make sure to use gsed instead of sed on AIX and of course put the "-i" back in.

Or write the output of sed to a temp-file, and afterwards move the temp file back to the original file...

Note: don't redirect stdout directly to the same file, or it will be emptied before it's contents are seen by "sed".

Comment: PS: in  `sed "s/${AGRP}\/&${ACCT1}/" /etc/test`   there is a bad backslash before the middle slash.

Comment: one more thing:  `AGRP="$(grep ^w3b3root /etc/group)"`  will likely give you a little less headache.

Comment: While I've never had an issue using the "old school" back ticks, I updated the variable with the parens and entered the command in your first comment - still getting the "cannot be parsed" error.  Our AIX servers do not have gsed installed.

Comment: In that case then you need the "Or"-part of my answer:  You need to redirect each sed's output to a temp-file, and then, in a separate step, move the temp-file back onto the original.    (That is, what "-i" essentially does in gnu version of "sed" on linux, and installable as "). -- 

The point is: just leaving out the "-i" will leave the original files unchanged - you have to manually write the stdout of sed back to the file, but mind the "Note:" in the answer.

Comment: the "cannot be parsed" error also needs to be fixed.  As I mentioned in first comment to this answer, the parse error only came up with a variant, where you had an extra backslash in it.

Comment: regarding your comment to bakunins answer, you might be mixing up chuser with chown. - just as you are naming it together with chgrp...   -- chuser is something different than chown --  I have to write this comment  here, because my reputation is not yet enough to comment on the other answer.

Comment: I'll test out the redirection, but as a test I was just trying to get the command to work (outputting it to the screen) without writing it to any file.  As far as bakunins, I don't think he read/understood my original post - these are AD accounts being added to local groups, therefore running any of the built-in commands do not work as they do not see AD accounts.  I also added in the Linux portion as a point of reference as to what I was doing, which I think confused him as well.

Comment: I think I figured it out:  sed "s/${AGRP}/${AGRP}${ACCT1}/" /etc/test > /etc/test2

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the GNUism "-i", which is not part of what what the POSIX standard prescribes for sed. It is dangerous anyway.

Second, you shouldn't modify /etc/group this way anyway. AIX has the chuser command and the chgrp command and I suggest you use these. If you want to add a user to a certain group i suggest you consult the man-page of chuser.

Furthermore, there is no "wheel" group in standard AIX, this is not a Linux system! The group with GID 0 (I suppose this is what you look for) is called "system".

Comment: We have both AIX AND Linux servers - I have the Linux portion working, as noted above.  Second, these are AD accounts being added to local grounds - you cannot run chuser and chgrp, the commands do not see the accounts.....so as I stated in my first post, you have to manually edit /etc/group.

Comment: @Dana: "Active Directory" is basically a dumbed-down LDAP with Kerberos V for authentication. Here is the IBM documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/active-directory-ad-aix-step-step-instructions-integrate-active-directory-2016-aix-ldap-protocol